# Бот discord который ставит реакцию на сообщения

Tags: discord, бот

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Нужен бот discord который будет автоматически ставить определение реакции в определенном канале.

Comment: Вы, вероятно, перепутали этот ресурс с фриланс-биржей, где можно кому-то заплатить, чтобы он вам сделал все ваши хотелки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создание нужного вам Embed:

```
embed = discord.Embed(
    title="Канал для отправки заявки на сервер",
    description=f"**Чтобы подать заявку напишите свой ник**\n**Перед тем как писать свой ник ознакомьтесь с Правилами сервера**❗\n**Статусы:**\n - заявка в обработке\n✅ - вас добавили на сервер\n❌ - ваша заявка отклонена",
    color=16073462,
)
msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Для того, чтобы поставить реакцию под сообщением используйте:

```
await msg.add_reaction("ID реакции")
```

Для того чтобы получить ID реакции - в любом текстовом канале поставьте `\` перед эмодзи:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]